# Set the woocommerce email header background image

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am trying to set the email header background image.
[image]

And I am trying to modify the email template file `email-header.php`.
Also, I put the img in the same dir with the `email-header.php` -> `theme->my-theme->woocommerce->email`
And here is my code:

```
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_container">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top" >
                         //add the custom img
                            <img src="email_header-graphic.jpg" alt="" style="width:auto; height:auto;">
                                <!-- Header -->
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_header">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="header_wrapper">
                                            <h1><?php echo $email_heading; ?></h1>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
```

However, it isn't work. How I can modify the template header to a image?

Thanks for helping.

---

New:

Trying to modify the `email-styles.php`:

```
 #template_header {

border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0 !important;
background-image: url("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . "/woocommerce/email"; ?>/email_header-graphic.jpg");
border-bottom: 0;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
   }
```

And the inspect display a different link:

```
https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/....../http://myweb.com.hk/wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/email/email_header-graphic.jpg
```

And I am trying to add the background image on the css. Also I display the color of the header. Now is this:

[image]

Comment: https://www.sellwithwp.com/customizing-woocommerce-order-emails/

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, can you be more specific?

Comment: I don't know is this way going right. I am try to modify the `email-style.php`. Update the new situation later.

Comment: I'd suggest filtering `woocommerce_email_styles` instead of overriding the template for this. Presumably, you need an explicit URL and not a relative URL as relative to the email doesn't really exist.

Comment: I am trying to get the actually link by using `echo get_template_directory_uri() . "/woocommerce/email"; ?>/email_header-graphic.jpg`, but the email still cannot display the Img

Answer (score 2):

I'd go about a different way than what you are trying to do.  I'd put the image in "background" in the header table found in email-header.php like so:

```
<!-- Header -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_header"  background="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/email-bg.png">
<tr>
    <td id="header_wrapper">
        <h1><?php echo $email_heading; ?></h1>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- End Header -->
```

Make sure to add the image "email-bg.png" to your uploads folder, or edit the file path and file name accordingly.  I also recommend setting the "base color" in WooCommerce => Settings => Emails so that it displays a color you like when images are not shown (email images often aren't shown by default).

Tip: Be sure to create a woocommerce/emails/email-header.php file in your theme directory so your updates aren't overwritten by an update.